# How to have multiple variables in an ampscript if/then statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm having a hard to understanding how to create a simple if/then statement in ampscript.  I'm trying to display some text if a variable I set up doesn't contain certain text strings.

```
%%[if @MyVariable != "this" AND "that" AND "theOther" then]%%
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  Is there a problem with my syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like most other languages, you have to actually specify the variable each time:

```
%%[if @MyVariable != "this" AND @MyVariable != "that" AND @MyVariable != "theOther" then]%%
```